Invoke-PnPTenantTemplate -Verbose will raise this error "Acquiring oAuth token for permission scope Group.ReadWrite.All. Access token acquired"
I have 2 office 365 tenants (Source & Destination). I used this command to get the Source communication site template inside my PowerShell 7.0 version 7.3.4:-
PS C:\Users\mohan> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://source.sharepoint.com/sites/PPM-test/" -Interactive

PS C:\Users\mohan> Get-PnPSiteTemplate -Out "PnP-Provisioning-F.xml"

where i got this file:-
enter image description here
Then when i tried to apply this template to a new communication site at the destination tenant, i got those errors/messages and the process will end after 3 seconds without applying the template:-
PS C:\Users\mohan> Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://destination.sharepoint.com/sites/PPM-test/" -Interactive

PS C:\Users\mohan> Invoke-PnPTenantTemplate -Path "PnP-Provisioning-F.xml"

here are the errors:-
VERBOSE: Acquiring oAuth token for permission scope Group.ReadWrite.All
VERBOSE: Access token acquired

enter image description here
any advice ? what is causing this error? I login to the destination using the site collection admin which is also an office 365 SharePoint admin. So why I am getting Access token Required? looks strange?
Thanks in advance for any help.

@FrankThomas yes using the Connect-PnPOnline i got a login dialog, where i entered a valid username /password and i approved the MFA

@FrankThomas the last result i got will beVERBOSE: Access token acquired.. and the process will end without applying the template

ok I recommend you edit your question to indicate that. I don;t see anything about the actual outcome in your question, just the log messages that don't indicate an error.

@FrankThomas ok thanks for the advice i edited my question accordingly
